# Intermediate stream operations not evaluated on count

Tags: java, java-stream

It seems I'm having trouble understanding how Java composes stream operations into a stream pipeline.

When executing the following code

```
public
 static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    var count = Stream.of(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"})
            .map(sb::append)
            .count();

    System.out.println(count);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The console only prints `4`. The `StringBuilder` object still has the value `""`.

When I add the filter operation: `filter(s -> true)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    var count = Stream.of(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"})
            .filter(s -> true)
            .map(sb::append)
            .count();

    System.out.println(count);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The output changes to:

```
4
1234
```

How does this seemingly redundant filter operation change the behavior of the composed stream pipeline?

Comment: Interesting !!!

Comment: I would imagine this is implementation-specific behaviour; perhaps it's because the first stream has a known size, but the second one doesn't, and the sized-ness determines whether the intermediate operations are executed.

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you reverse the filter and map?

Comment: Having programmed a bit in Haskell, it smells a bit like some lazy evaluation going on here. A google search returned, that streams indeed have some laziness. Might that be the case? And without a filter, if java is clever enough, there is no need to actually execute the mapping.

Comment: @AndyTurner It gives the same result, even on reversal

Comment: This also explains why `Arrays.stream(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"}).peek(System.out::println).count();` doesn't do what one might expect.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `count()` terminal operation, in my version of the JDK, ends up executing the following code:

```
if (StreamOpFlag.SIZED.isKnown(helper.getStreamAndOpFlags()))
    return spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown();
return super.evaluateSequential(helper, spliterator);
```

If there is a `filter()` operation in the pipeline of operations, the size of the stream, which is known initially, can't be known anymore (since `filter` could reject some elements of the stream). So the `if` block is not executed, the intermediate operations are executed and the StringBuilder is thus modified.

On the other hand, If you only have `map()`in the pipeline, the number of elements in the stream is guaranteed to be the same as the initial number of elements. So the if block is executed, and the size is returned directly without evaluating the intermediate operations.

Note that the lambda passed to `map()` violates the contract defined in the documentation: it's supposed to be a non-interfering, stateless operation, but it is not stateless. So having a different result in both cases can't be considered as a bug.

Comment: Because `flatMap()` might be able to change the number of elements, was that the reason why it was initially eager (now lazy)? 

So, the alternative would be to use `forEach()` and count separately if `map()` in its current form violates the contract, I guess.

Comment: Regarding flatMap, I don't think so. It was, AFAIK, because it was simpler initialy to make it eager. Yes, using a stream, with map(), to produce side effects is a bad idea.

Comment: Would you have a suggestion on how to achieve the full output 
`4 1234` without utilizing the extra filter or producing side effects in the map() operation?

Comment: `int count = array.length; String result = String.join("", array);`

Comment: Yes, I see. For the post, I actually simplified the underlying problem to just a simple Array of Strings so getting the wanted output is trivial. However, I just changed my streams a bit and it works now without any redundant filters or side effects in the map operation. Thanks!

Comment: or you could use forEach if you really want to use a StringBuilder, or you could use `Collectors.joining("")`

Answer (score 24):

In [jdk-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) it was clearly documented in java docs

> The eliding of side-effects may also be surprising. With the exception of terminal operations forEach and forEachOrdered, side-effects of behavioral parameters may not always be executed when the stream implementation can optimize away the execution of behavioral parameters without affecting the result of the computation. (For a specific example see the API note documented on the [count](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) operation.)

**API Note:**

> **An implementation may choose to not execute the stream pipeline (either sequentially or in parallel) if it is capable of computing the count directly from the stream source. In such cases no source elements will be traversed and no intermediate operations will be evaluated.** Behavioral parameters with side-effects, which are strongly discouraged except for harmless cases such as debugging, may be affected. For example, consider the following stream:

```
 List<String> l = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
 long count = l.stream().peek(System.out::println).count();
```

> **The number of elements covered by the stream source, a List, is known and the intermediate operation, peek, does not inject into or remove elements from the stream (as may be the case for flatMap or filter operations).** Thus the count is the size of the List and there is no need to execute the pipeline and, as a side-effect, print out the list elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is not what .map is for. It is supposed to be used to turn a stream of "Something" into a stream of "Something Else". In this case, you are using map to append a string to an external Stringbuilder, after which you have a stream of "Stringbuilder", each of which was created by the map operation appending one number to the original Stringbuilder.

Your stream doesn't actually do anything with mapped results in the stream, so it's perfectly reasonable to assume that the step can be skipped by the stream processor. You're counting on side effects to do the work, which breaks the functional model of the map. You'd be better served by using forEach to do this. Do the count as a separate stream entirely, or put a counter using AtomicInt in the forEach.

The filter forces it to run the stream contents since the it now has to do something notionally meaningful with each stream element.